# Mock internal dependencys of requireJS

Tags: javascript, testing, mocking, requirejs

I user squireJS to mock dependencys while testing my (requirejs) app. This works as long as I have no "internal" dependencys.

Example:

```
define(["controller/Storage"], function (StorageController) {
  //some code

   require(["controller/Communication"], function (CommunicationController) {

   });

});
```

I need to have the second require statement due to a cycling dependency. Anyway, I can mock each dependency defined in the define(....) block, but none of these in the require block.

Any ideas?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269119/how-to-mock-inline-requirejs-dependencies-with-squire-for-unit-testing for a potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

The first thought that comes to mind is using the [map config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map) to point references of `controller/Communication` to some form of mock.

You would need to redefine your `require.config()` for the tests though, which is not uncommon usually.