# How to mock inline requirejs dependencies with squire for unit testing?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, requirejs, mocha.js, squirejs

I'm using requirejs with inline requires, for instance:

```
define(['someDep'], function(someDep) {
  return {
    someFn: function() {
      require(['anotherDep'], function(anotherDep) {
        anotherDep.anotherFn();
      });
    }
  } 
});
```

In my particular case, I cannot include `anotherDep` in the define.

When testing with mocha, I have a test case like this:

```
define(['squire'], function(Squire) {
  var squire = new Squire();
  describe('testcase', function() {
    it('should mock anotherDep', function(done) {
      var spy = sinon.spy();
      squire.mock('anotherDep', {
        anotherFn: spy
      });
      squire.require(['someDep'], function(someDep) {
        someDep.someFn();
        expect(spy).to.have.been.calledOnce;
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

fails because `anotherDep` calls `require` directly and not `squire.require`.  The work-around is to replace `require` in the global scope,

```
var originalRequire;

before(function() {
  originalRequire = require;
  require = _.bind(squire.require, squire);
});

after(function() {
  require = originalRequire;
});
```

This works (note that `squire.require` must be bound to the `squire` object in some way, I'm using underscore to do this) except that the spy will still not be called because of timing.  The test also has to change to

```
it('should mock anotherDep', function(done) {
  squire.mock('anotherDep', {
    anotherFn: function() {
      done();
    }
  });
  squire.require(['someDep'], function(someDep) {
    someDep.someFn();
  });
});
```

Is there a better way?  If not, hope this provides a solution for others running into the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not tried to do specifically what you are trying to do but it seems to me that if squire is doing a thorough job, then requiring the `require` module should give you what you want without having to mess with the global `require`. The `require` module is a special (and reserved) module that makes available a local `require` function. It is necessary for instance when you use the Common JS syntactic sugar. However, you can use it whenever you desire to get a local `require`. Again, if squire does a thorough job, then the `require` it gives you should be one that squire controls rather than some sort of pristine `require`.

So:

```
define(['require', 'someDep'], function (require, someDep) {
  return {
    someFn: function() {
      require(['anotherDep'], function(anotherDep) {
        anotherDep.anotherFn();
      });
    }
  } 
});
```

Comment: This works perfectly.  At first I was hesitant to modify my modules to include depending on 'require' as a module as it seems a bit hacky and unnecessary, but after some thought I realized this is really about writing testable code and if doing this allows code to be unit-testable then it is a worthwhile pattern to put in place.

Comment: Glad to help! Let me note that there is no hack here. Putting `require` in the dependencies is part of the public API of RequireJS, and is in fact necessary for some use cases (besides the one I've mentioned in my answer).